# How to handle Limma dependency when Submitting to CRAN

Tags: r, dependencies

I want to submit my package to CRAN.

Do I need to declare Bioconductor-dependencies such as Limma differently in the Description-File of my Package?

Currently I am declaring limma like this:

```
Suggests: 
limma
```

Can CRAN identify that limma is a Bioconductor-Package and will it Limma install, when installing my package from CRAN?

I was also wondering if its necessary. i specify limma in description and namespace to make sure my package has no Errors when running he Check, but my function doesnt need Limma. I only need it for an example. The user could install limma himself if he wants to run my example.